# How to send a message from my name (my account, not the bot) in Telegram using Python?

Tags: python

I already have the main script. Now I only need the method that will send a certaing message from my account (my name) to another person automatically. Is it possible to send messages that way?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use the [Telegram Database Library](https://core.telegram.org/tdlib), which is a set of APIs you can use to control your user's actions via HTTP requests. Then you'll use the sendMessage class to send a message as yourself. The [Get Started page](https://core.telegram.org/tdlib/getting-started#user-authorization) pretty much has everything you need for your project.

Source: https://core.telegram.org/#tdlib-build-your-own-telegram